# What's the average power-on hours for a NEW hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I just purchased a hard disk from a stall in a kind-of-shady computer center. I'm worried this might be a resold drive (second hand) and I've been told how bad they can be. I've checked with [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/) and it states it has been powered on for 2500 hours. Is this a new disk?

Comment: 2500 hours is 104 days - so no, this is not a new disk.

Comment: oh boy, time to get a refund...

Answer (score 0):

The individual time will vary but as a general rule any drive with over 24-48 hours should be considered used. With that number of hours there is no doubt it is second hand and should be returned. especially if they advertised it as a "new" drive.